# Check if a framework is linked at precompile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, precompile

Is there a precompiler directive that checks if a framework is linked in an Obj-C/Cocoa project?

For example, I have a class of useful categories with some MapKit categories. However, if MapKit is not linked to the framework, then those categories will not compile.

Is there anything like:

```
#ifdef MAPKIT
....
// Only compiles if MapKit framework is linked to the current project
....
#endif
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Macro evaluation is done long before the link phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Preprocessing and compilation happens at one build phase -- *Linking* is a separate phase.

Xcode does not provide an easy way for you to access/enumerate the build settings related to linking in a source file.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew that macro evaluation was done during linking phase.

Answer (score 2):

MapKit would also require a header file.
MKFoundation.h defines `MK_EXTERN`.
You could check for that.

`#ifdef MK_EXTERN`

`#endif`

Comment: there's no reason MapKit's headers would need to be precompiled. it's actually a bad idea to add the world to the PCH.

Comment: but defines like these may help you to fire up warning that you forgot to include that particular framework instead of sometimes confusing linking error which you need to google to find out what's missing from project